# C# sbyte is written to the file as an unsigned byte

Tags: c#

Using the `BinaryWriter` I write an `sbyte` variable to a file but it gets written to the file as unsigned and not signed as it should be.

```
sbyte a = (sbyte)image.pixelData[i + 0];
bw.Write(a);
```

For example, the above code writes values ranging from `0x00` to `0xFF`. (These are the values I see in a hex editor.)

Comment: how do you write it in ? how do you read it from ? some code...

Comment: Show us how you arrived at this conclusion. (Note: All values are written to the file as binary bits.)

Comment: sbyte a = (sbyte)image.pixelData[i + 0];   
bw.Write(a);

The written data has values up ranging from 0-255 and not -127 to 127

Comment: here is where you can find the answer to your life's question http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#The_number_42

Comment: @TGE: How did you inspect the values that were written? (And update your question, for God's sake.)

Comment: I looked at it in a hex editor

Comment: If you write the signed value -100 to a file and then look at it in a hex editor, what hex digits would you expect to see?  In other words, how is a negative number expressed in hex?

Comment: doing that returns 0x9C. Thing is, the alpha value is written as 0xFF. That's 255 but it should be in the -127 to 127 range because that's the range of a signed byte

Comment: I think if you edit your comments into the question this should be re-opened, as it's not at all unclear now what you're asking. Others may experience the same misunderstanding at some point and be helped by this question.

Comment: (I added the mention of the hex editor to the question, as it makes the situation much clearer in my opinion.)

Answer (score 3):

You are demonstrating a fundamental misunderstanding of how data is stored in memory, files, etc.

***All* computer data is in binary form.**

The different data types determine how the data is treated, how calculations are performed, how values are formatted, etc.

If you write a signed value to a file, it is always written using binary form (the only format a computer understands). If you read that data with a hex editor, then the hex editor will translate the data using whatever translation it considers to be appropriate.

If you write data to a file as a signed byte, and then you read that same data back as a signed byte, then the data will be the same as the data written. You should expect no more, and no less.

*(Note: If you use the hex editor I wrote ([Cygnus Hex Editor](http://www.softcircuits.com/cygnus/)), you can inspect the data using any data type. In that case, you can have it appear in the format you expect. Otherwise, the hex editor is converting it to hex, or whatever, which tells you nothing about how the data is stored in the file.)*